# Comment appelle-t-on l'endroit où on s'assoit sur une bicyclette ?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, transports

Lequel des deux mots est le plus approprié dans « Je souhaite changer le (*siège*/*dossier*) sur ma bicyclette » ?

Comment: Le regretté Raymond Devos voulait changer la selle de cette bicyclette ci avec celle de cette bicyclette là, car la sonnette de celle-ci fait la et la sonnette de celle-là fait si.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La chose sur laquelle on s'assoit lorsque l'on fait de la bicyclette n'est jamais appelée un dossier ni un siège mais une selle.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/selle)) 3. P. anal. Petit siège, le plus souvent de cuir, d'un cycle ou d'un véhicule à deux roues à moteur. Une bonne selle [de bicyclette] doit être simple de ressorts et être assez dure

Il faut expliquer le mot « jamais » ; on n'emploiera jamais le mot « siège » dans le contexte normal d'utilisation d'une bicyclette mais on pourra l'employer dans une explication de ce qu'est une selle. C'est pareil dans le cas de la forme en cuir que l'on met sur les chevaux avant de s'asseoir sur leur dos ; c'est aussi appelé une selle et on ne dira jamais « siège » pour nommer cette chose, à moins de vouloir expliquer ce que c'est. La précision qui reste à faire c'est que l'on ne dit *absolument* jamais « dossier ».

Comment: Il peut y avoir un *siège* sur un vélo,  mais c'est alors un siège ajouté pour y asseoir un enfant, en plus de la *selle*.

Comment: On peut aussi trouver à la place du siège pour enfant ce qui est appelé un *porte- bagages*  ou plus précisément un porte-bagage arrière, mais que des personnes pas trop corpulentes peuvent utiliser comme siège ; néanmoins on appelle toujours ce siège un porte- bagages (on dit par exemple « s'asseoir sur le porte-bagages »).

Answer (score 0):

it'd be better to say : 
« Je souhaite changer ***la selle de*** ma bicyclette »